# listview scrolls to top after editing entry

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a listview that when you click on an entry you may modify it and after hitting confirm it will still show the entry you just modified instead of scrolling to the top.

made advised changes and after leaving the edit activity it still scrolls to the top and does not find the correct scroll position. am i missing something?

```
static int firstPosition = 0;

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Cursor c = mNotesCursor;
    ListView mListView = getListView();
    firstPosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, QuoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra(QuotesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    i.putExtra(QuotesDBAdapter.KEY_QUOTES, c.getString(
    c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuotesDBAdapter.KEY_QUOTES)));
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}
    public void onResume(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
ListView mListView = getListView();

if (mListView != null && firstPosition >= 0){
   mListView.scrollTo(0,firstPosition);
//  mListView.setSelection(firstPosition);

}

}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        switch(requestCode) {
            case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
                String title = extras.getString(QuotesDBAdapter.KEY_QUOTES);
                mDbHelper.createQuote(title);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_EDIT: 
                ListView mListView = getListView();
                Long rowId = extras.getLong(QuotesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
                if (rowId != null) {
                    String editTitle = extras.getString(QuotesDBAdapter.KEY_QUOTES);
                    mDbHelper.updateQuote(rowId, editTitle);
                    mListView.setSelection(firstPosition);
                }
                fillData();
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = ex.toString();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Extend with the custom adapter rather then instance. then onclick, inflate the layout, change already `Gone` layout to `VISIBLE`. Set its value to listitem clicked text. Then, add a confirm button also in that layout. and onclick, `notify` the adapter and refresh list!

Comment: It looks like your editor is another activity, is that right?

Comment: If it so, editor is another activity, then it is not a good practice. Try visible the hidden layout having the textbox and button.

Comment: yes its another activity

Comment: could you show me an example? im pretty confused. it seems like i should remake my edit so its not another activity?

Comment: Your editor should definitely be another Activity - that's not a problem. You just have to do the scrolling in `onActivityResult()` - see my answer below.

Comment: You should try to make `ListView mListView = getListView();` global to activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor is another `Activity`, which you are calling with `startActivityForResult()`. This line doesn't actually stop here - it will continue processing the rest of the method, including the `mListView.setSelection(firstPosition);` statement. In other words, `setSelection()` is called before the user gets to edit the value.

When the editor `Activity` is closed, it will return the result to `onActivityResult()`. In this method, you will need to tell it to scroll the `ListView` to the correct position again. So maybe something like this...

```
static int firstPosition = 0; // this is a global variable - set it in onListItemClick()

public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    mListView.setSelection(firstPosition);
    }
```

And change your `onListItemClick()` method to use the global variable, like this...

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Cursor c = mNotesCursor;
    ListView mListView = getListView();
    firstPosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); // changed this line
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, QuoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra(QuotesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    i.putExtra(QuotesDBAdapter.KEY_QUOTES, c.getString(
    c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(QuotesDBAdapter.KEY_QUOTES)));
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    mListView.setSelection(firstPosition);
}
```

Now, the `setSelection()` method doesn't change the scroll position, but you could try this...

In `onListItemClick()`, change to the following...

```
    firstPosition = mListView.getScrollY();
```

And in `onActivityResult()`, change to the following...

```
    mlistView.scrollTo(0,firstPosition);
```

Possibly also add the following code to the end of your `onResume()` method (in your main `Activity`), so that it is run when you return back to the main `Activity`...

```
ListView mListView = getElementById("myListView");
if (mlistView != null && firstPosition >= 0){
    mlistView.scrollTo(0,firstPosition);
}
```

Comment: I have added some lines to the end of my answer - give those a try.

Comment: What about adding `mlistView.scrollTo(0,firstPosition);` to the end of your `onResume()` method (see my edited answer)

Comment: i didnt have an on resume method (is that bad?) so i added one and still no luck

Comment: Are you able to debug your code in Eclipse? Put a breakpoint in each of the `onActivityResult()` and `onResume()` methods - see whether the list is scrolling to the correct location in these methods (it might be being reset by a later method). Also, put a breakpoint in `onListItemClick()` and see what value is stored in `firstPosition = mListView.getScrollY();` - it might be setting the value `0` which means that this is the wrong piece of code.

Comment: That's great! Don't forget to tick my answer as 'accepted' so that everyone knows that your question has been solved. Good luck with the rest of your project.